# Is it desirable to use java reflection to implement findByXXX method of list class?

Tags: java, oop

we have Book class like this:

```java
public class Book {
  String name, isbn, author, publisher;
  int publishedYear, price;
}
```

and BookList class extends Arraylist:

```java
public class BookList extends ArrayList<Book> {

  BookList searchBookByName(String name) {
    BookList matchedBooks = new BookList();
    for (Book book : this) {
      if (book.name.equals(name)) {
        matchedBooks.add(book);
      }
    }
    return matchedBooks;
  }
}
```

If you want to additionally write searchBookByXXX methods with different search field, there is four string field and I think the implementation of the method will be same as the searchBookByName method.

It would be definitely the violation of dry principle.

So in this case is it desirable to use java reflection? or are there any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection would not be the ideal choice. Typically you should only use reflection if it's absolutely required. The better option would be to create a more general method that the other methods delegate to:

```
public BookList searchBookBy(java.util.function.Predicate<? super Book> filter) {
  BookList matchedBooks = new BookList();
  for (Book book : this) {
    if (filter.test(book)) {
      matchedBooks.add(book);
    }
  }
  return matchedBooks;
}

public BookList searchBookByName(String name) {
  return searchBookBy(book -> book.getName().equals(name));
}
```

If you want to use streams then the `searchBookBy` method can be changed to:

```java
public BookList searchBookBy(java.util.function.Predicate<? super Book> filter) {
  return stream().filter(filter).collect(Collectors.toCollection(BookList::new));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
<T> BookList search(T key, Function<Book, T> getter) {
    return stream()
        .filter(book -> getter.apply(book).equals(key))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(BookList::new));
}

BookList searchBookByName(String key) { return search(key, book -> book.name); }
BookList searchBookByIsbn(String key) { return search(key, book -> book.isbn); }
BookList searchBookByAuthor(String key) { return search(key, book -> book.author); }
BookList searchBookByPublisher(String key) { return search(key, book -> book.publisher); }
BookList searchBookByPublishedYear(int key) { return search(key, book -> book.publishedYear); }
BookList searchBookByPrice(int key) { return search(key, book -> book.price); }
```

Comment: This would be an alternative solution. Thank you!

Comment: 1+, but I think using a `Predicate` makes it easier to understand compared to passing a `Function` (and key).

Answer (score 2):

I think reflection would be a terrible choice.

You've had one method suggesting a filter class. Another possibility would be to define an enum within your class, accessible by callers, to be passed in to a find method to indicate the field on which to find. The filter is more general, the enums are perhaps easier to understand.

EDIT:

I threw this together very quickly; I have not even compiled it, it's just for illustration. Sorry, it's bedtime where I am...

```
public class Booklist
{
  public enum FieldType { NAME, ISBN, AUTHOR, PUBLISHER, PUBLISHED_YEAR, PRICE };

  private HashMap<FieldType, BookFilter> fieldTypeFilters;

  static
  {
    fieldTypeFilters.put(NAME, new NameFilter);
    fieldTypeFilters.put(ISBN, new IsbnFilter);
    fieldTypeFilters.put(AUTHOR, new AuthorFilter);
    fieldTypeFilters.put(PUBLISHER, new PublisherFilter);
    fieldTypeFilters.put(PUBLISHED_YEAR, new PublishedYearFilter);
    fieldTypeFilters.put(PRICE, new PriceFilter);
  }

  BookList searchBooks(FieldType fieldType, Object value)
  {
    BookFilter filter = fieldTypeFilters.get(fieldType);
    BookList matchedBooks = search(value, filter);
  }

  private class NameFilter
  {
    public boolean test(Book book, Object targetName)
    {
      return book.getName().equals(targetName.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was able to fine the enum solution at selenium. I think it is the most understandable solution.

Comment: And there's no reason you can't have enums for the search-a-single-field case, and filters for a more general case. You can define (innerclass?) filters for each single-field case, and the enum calls can obtain the correct filter with a map and then call the filter version.

Comment: why would it be a terrible choice to use reflection?
I think in a findBy... operation where the bottleneck is the DB, the time to perform reflection should be negligeable.
However, I'm not sure you can do something this dynamic in Java. Because during compile time it needs to know that the method is there. I'm not sure how one would get around that.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the enum approach? I'm struggling with how it could be more readable while also maintaining type safety.

Comment: @AminM Reflection is less readable and you lose all compile-time type safety. Only use reflection if there's no other choice (or if the alternative would be _significantly_ more work to implement/maintain).

Comment: @Slaw fair enough

Comment: Good solution. As a variation, each new `…Filter` object could be passed to the enum’s constructor, and saved as a member field of the enum.